# How do i apply a command to each line in the output from pipe and add all those numbers?

Tags: command-line, grep, awk

I have a command that outputs the following file sizes in multiple lines:

```
32G
16K
2M
```

The requirement is to convert them into bytes by using the command `numfmt` and add all the bytes:

- `numfmt --from=iec 32G` [res: 34359738368 bytes]
- `numfmt --from=iec 16K` [res: 16384 bytes]
- `numfmt --from=iec 2M`  [res: 2097152 bytes]

The desired output is ***34359738368 + 16384 + 2097152***, the sum of all sizes in bytes.

Assume all the inputs are stored in a file called `temp.txt`. I tried this command but it is throwing errors:

```bsh
cat temp.txt | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0}; {sum+= system(numfmt --from=iec $0) }  END {print sum;}'
```

Comment: This is where `xargs` is really handy ...

Comment: You can read about the `system` function [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html). Your main error is not providing a string as a parameter, but your main misconception is that system() returns the *output* of the command: it does not. [Read this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html) to find out how to call an external command and capture the output.

Comment: you're right @glennjackman, i assumed system functions work anywhere I called, and looks like i need to look into the documentation you pointed to. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in calling `numfmt` from within awk - why not simply pipe your data *through* it?

```
$ numfmt --from=iec <temp.txt | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'
34361851904
```

or (to mimic data piped from a command) for example

```
$ cat temp.txt | numfmt --from=iec | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}' | numfmt --to=iec
33G
```

---

If you *really* want to call `numfmt` line-by-line from within awk, then you can do so in GNU awk (gawk) using [`getline` from a Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html)

Ex.

```
$ cat temp.txt | gawk '
    BEGIN{cmd = "numfmt --from=iec"} 
    {print $0 |& cmd; close(cmd,"to"); cmd |& getline; sum+=$0; close(cmd,"from")} 
    END{print sum}
'
34361851904
```

See

- [Two-Way Communications with Another Process](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html)

Comment: @daylightsaving note how you don't need to initialize the sum variable: awk treats unset variables as the empty string or the number zero, depending on the context.

Comment: thanks @steeldriver, 2nd command, piping it into many commands worked.